# filter a power bi report according to the value of a parameter

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

is it possible to filter a report according to the value of a parameter.

let me explain:

I have a report that shows me the sales, turnover... from several agencies (6000), I would like each agency director to have access to just the appalling information about his agency, I thought I forced each user to enter the code of his agency when he wants to access the report and the report will automatically filter itself and display only the information that corresponds to that agency.

I don't know if it's possible to do this with Power BI or how to do it.

Comment: Is this report just in Power BI Desktop, in the cloud or on a local report server? Where is the source data stored?

Comment: Security by inputing the number of the agency "to have access" without any other authentication is not secure, i can just input any number until I guess it. 
If you want to secure your data, you can take advantage of Row Level Security at your datasource if supported.
Or if published to Power BI Service or Power BI Report Server, you can use Power BI's own Row Level Security.

Comment: the source of my report is a CSV file, and my report will be published on  bower bi server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you will publish your report to Power BI Report Server, you have two approaches using Row Level Security.

You can go for a more Static approach, setup one Role for each agency, and filter your agency table.

Or you can create a table that maps users to agencies, and use the USERNAME(), dax function to filter your data.

[Power BI Report Server - Row Level Security](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/report-server/row-level-security-report-server)